# Adding data to a nested list in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a nested list e.g.:

```
nlist = [
         [1, 2, 3], 
         [4, 5, 6], 
         [7, 8, 9],
        ]
```

Before I insert this list into a database, I would like to add a "column" to it with the same value in each row of the new column e.g:

```
nlist = [
            [a, 1, 2, 3], 
            [a, 4, 5, 6], 
            [a, 7, 8, 9],
           ]
```

What's the best way to do this, when, for example, the original nested list might have hundreds of rows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not change the original list (if that is all you want to do):

```
for row in nlist:
    row.insert(0, a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to create a new list then this will work as well...

```
nlistnew = [[a]+row for row in nlist]
```

**EDIT:** Fixed code as per Felix Kling's comment. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[[a]+row for row in nlist]` ?

Comment: Whoops: too cocky with my Python skillz and didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your outer list.  For each inner list use list method `insert(0, new_data)`.