# Adding new element at the end in each internal list of list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of list like below:

```
[[1,345,0,304],[0,345,678,946,90],[0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0]]
```

Now I want to append a new number (same number) to each of internal list at the end.

so result should be like:

```
[[1,345,0,304,90],[0,345,678,946,90,90],[0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0,90]]
```

I want to use a list comprehension as I don't want to do it the normal way by iterating over each internal list in main list and then use a temporary list to add to it.

Any help?

Comment: You can go a long way in improving this question by clarifying your intent. You claim that you want to append to each list using a list comprehension, but you've selected an answer which creates a copy, appending to those lists instead of the lists you mention. If that's what you want, please edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approaches**

Native Python (@acushner presented this first):

```
lsts = [[1,345,0,304], [0,345,678,946,90], [0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0]]
[lst + [90] for lst in lsts]
```

Alternatively, with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools as it

[list(it.chain(lst, [90])) for lst in lsts]
```

For fun, a third-party library [`more-itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.padded) (`pip install more_itertools`):

```
import more_itertools as mit

[list(mit.padded(lst, fillvalue=90, n=len(lst)+1)) for lst in lsts]
```

---

**Caveat**

Some answers attempt to mutate a list while iterating.  While those options give equivalent results, are possibly more memory efficient and may even be faster for larger data for this specific problem, they are arguably non-pythonic and not recommended practices.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

> It is sometimes tempting to change a list while you are looping over it; however, it is often simpler and safer to create a new list instead.

This is especially true when [*removing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list) or [*inserting*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633938/4531270) elements from a list while iterating it.  The latter approaches adopt this convention of creating a new list.  However, for certain innocuous [circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285521/adding-data-to-a-nested-list-in-python), a compromise may be iterating over a copy of the nested list:

```
lists = [[1,345,0,304], [0,345,678,946,90], [0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0]]
for lst in lists[:]:
    lst.append(90)
lists
```

Otherwise, default to @acushner's approach, which is the next performant option discussed here.

Comment: This is tremendously wasteful because it creates copies of the list. It doesn't, in fact, append each list. It creates brand new lists. Imagine the asymptotic case of a 1000x1000 list of lists.

Comment: No copies are made.  New lists are created.  This is intentional and a common convention with list comprehensions in Python.  What alternative do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

you can just use list addition to accomplish this:

```
[l + [90] for l in lists]
```

Comment: This is tremendously wasteful because it creates copies of the list. It doesn't, in fact, append each list. It creates brand new lists. Imagine the asymptotic case of a 1000x1000 list of lists.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy yes it's wasteful, but if you read OP's question it's what he/she wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
lists = [[1,345,0,304],[0,345,678,946,90],[0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0]]
[l.append(90) for l in lists]
print(lists)
```

> [[1, 345, 0, 304, 90], [0, 345, 678, 946, 90, 90], [0, 23, 3, 56, 3,
>   5, 9, 0, 90]]

Comment: This solution is best because it mutates the data structure rather than creating a new one. That being said, this is not how you should use list comprehensions. The question is best answered with a for-loop.

Comment: Could you explain why list comprehensions shouldn't be used for this?

Comment: @Serjik This is not correct. It won't work since append returns None

Comment: @Baktaawar It absolutely works, just print the result, None is because append does not return a value

Comment: @Arya McCarthy : as your comment the best, why any other answers get an upvote and me getting the down ???

Comment: No clue. Your answer is best. My best guess is that someone is trying to popularize their own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
lists = [[1,345,0,304], [0,345,678,946,90], [0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0]]

for lst in lists:
    lst.append(90)

print lists
[[1, 345, 0, 304, 90],[0, 345, 678, 946, 90, 90],[0, 23, 3, 56, 3, 5, 9, 0, 90]]
```

Comment: Consider mutating a copy of the nested list (see post for rationale).  Also for clarity, I would swap the names of `lst` and `lists`.  Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: Mutating the same list you are iterating is not a best-practice.  In this case, it is harmless since you are not removing items, but a safer habit is to iterate a copy, e.g. `lists[:]`.  There are several posts of this kind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating.  Just substitute `for lst in lists[:]:`.

Comment: @pylang he is not asking to iterate a copy

Comment: I was suggesting an idiom to improve your answer.  See the cavaet I posted for more information.  Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

And another one:

```
lists = [[1,345,0,304],[0,345,678,946,90],[0,23,3,56,3,5,9,0]]
for _ in map(lambda x: x.append(90), lists):
    pass
```